# Should I remove unused desktop?

Tags: multiple-desktops

I am using the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  The family member who set it up for me downloaded several desktops for me to try in addition to the Ubuntu desktops including the GNOME, Xdce and KDE desktops.  I have found that I prefer the KDE 4.8 desktop.  I have read in your “Ask Ubuntu” that having several desktops can cause conflicts. The family member who set the system up said it would not cause conflicts as long as I did not use any of the other desktops. Should I remove all but the Ubuntu desktops and the KDE desktop which I prefer?  If so, how do I handle any shared applications such as the VLC media player?

Comment: Just FYI, removing DE isn't easy. While installing DE uses meta package, but removing that meta package doesn't remove all the components. Manual removal can causes damage. So if you are not facing any critical issue, let it be as it is.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no need to do that. Having more desktops installed means you'll get slightly more updates to download. You'll also get more apps than you need that will appear in menus, but if you don't find that particularly annoying, there's really no need to.

I have at least five desktops installed and I switch between them all the time. Apps are completely independent on the desktop. You don't even need to have a desktop installed in order to use VLC, for instance although that'd be slightly uncomfortable in most cases. :)

In fact, from time to time, I've mixed elements from different desktops at the same time, such as in this case, where I run Unity with two monitors and added a panel from Xfce on my second monitor (the bottom panel). That's fine.

[image]